# When I'm accessing memory values in my microcontroller why is it pointing to the end of my data value?

Tags: c, memory, memory-leaks, microcontroller, stm32

I'm trying to get the value of at an address in memory in my microcontroller. The address is at `0x1fff7000` and that's the start of the memory block (so anything before is undefined). In my code I have `char *ptr = (char *)BASE_ADDR;` where `#define BASE_ADDR ((uint32_t)0x1FFF7000)`. My value at `0x1FFF7000` is `0x12345678` and I know 100% that it's there.

In GDB, I'm doing `(gdb) p/x *ptr` and my return value is `$6 = 0x78`. Why is it at `0x78` and not returning `0x12345678` or even `0x12`?

Comment: I assume that value was stored as a 32-bit value in [little-endian order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Classical_example). Try using a pointer to `uint32_t` to look at that memory address.

Comment: what happens when you add a volatile to your define.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you have a little-endian system/mcu, which means least significant bytes are stored first. In your example, the `0x12345678`, stored as a 32 bit integer, is going to look as `78 56 34 12` as raw data in memory.

Answer (score 3):

define it as `uint32_t *ptr = (volatile char *)BASE_ADDR;` then read.

(char *) can reference the value from -128 to 127.

Also read about the endianess. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

As I wrote in your other questions - before you program uCs you need to learn some basics. Bitwise operations, endianess etc etc.